# Linear programming: minimizing difference between vectors Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, vector, minimize

I have the following equation which I wish to minimize by varying `x1` to `x5`.

```
y=[(x1*a+x2*b+x3*c+x4*d+x5*e)-z]
```

Here `a,b,c,d,e` and `z` are all vectors. The objective is to find a combination of `a,b,c,d,e` to match as closely as possible to `z`. Can this be done as a linear program or something similar? The constraints I have `(x1 + x2)=0.6` and `(x3 +x4 x5)=0.4` Using lsqlin set up as:

```
       a=[1;2;3];
    b=[2;5;1];
    c=[8;1;3];
    d=[6;2;1];
    e=[5;4;3];

    C=[a,b,c,d,e];
    z=[6;5;2];
    A=[1 1 0 0 0; 
       0 0 1 1 1] ;
    bounds=[0.6; 0.4];


   lb=zeros(5,1);
       x = lsqlin(C,z,A,bounds,[],[],lb);
```

But this returns the error:

> Warning: Large-scale algorithm requires at least as many equations as
>   variables
>       in C matrix; using medium-scale algorithm instead.
>
> > In lsqlin at 268  Optimization terminated.
>
> x =
>
> ```
> 0.0000
> 0.5319    
> -0.0000
> 0.5745
> 0.2979
> ```

Which ignores the equalities I am after.

Comment: Any inequality constraints, such as non-negativity?

Comment: Yes. I believe lb=zeros(5,1) gives this? But yes, all non-negative. But y can be negative if need be- but whatever minimizes y in absolute terms. i.e. such that the sum of the elements of y is as close to 0 as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you just have equality constraints and want to minimize the mean-squared error, you can solve this using `mrdivide`.

The unconstrained case is:

```
x = z / [a b c d e]
```

With the constraints, you have

> y = [(x1*a+x2*b+x3*c+x4*d+x5*e)-z] 
>   = [(x1*a+(.6-x1)*b+x3*c+x4*d+(.4-x3-x4)*e)-z]

So that

```
x = [0 .6 0 0 .4] + (z -.6*b - .4*e) / [a-b c-e d-e] * [1 0 0; -1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 -1 -1]';
```

For inequality constraints, you will need to set up a quadratic program and use a solver such as Simplex or interior-point methods.

The [`quadprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) MATLAB function should do that effectively.  [`lsqlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) looks like a good choice also, and probably easier to set up from the description you have.

Comment: thanks. lsqlin looks like exactly what I need but it gives me an error. I edit the question now.